# Finding an orthogonal basis for subspace spanned by vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

I have a linear algebra problem that I have been struggling with.

If $V$ is a vector space $C[0, 1$] with inner product defined by $\int_{0}^{1} fg dx$ for $f, g$ , find an orthogonal basis for Span{$1, x, x^2$}.

I recall having to do something with dot products, and from the inner product definition provided, I think I should integrate the functions from the Span. However, I am not really sure on how to proceed.

I have looked at a few examples on Stack Exchange, but none of which are very similar to this; I am still having difficulty understanding what to do.

Following the Gram-Schmidt Algorithm:

$v_1= \textbf{1}$

$v_2 = x - \frac{\int_{0}^{1} x dx}{\int_{0}^{1} 1 dx}$  = $\mathbf{x - 0.5}$

$v_3 = x^2 - \frac{\int_{0}^{1} x^2 dx}{\int_{0}^{1} 1 dx} - \frac{\int_{0}^{1} (x^3)(x - 0.5)}{\int_{0}^{1} (x - 0.5)^2} * (x - 0.5)$ = $\mathbf{x^2 - x + 1/6}$.

Normalizing the vectors:

$v_1 = \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1} 1 * 1 dx} = 1/2$

$v_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt {\int_{0}^{1} (x - 0.5)^2} dx} * (x - 0.5)$ = $ 2\sqrt{3}(x - 0.5)$

$v_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt {\int_{0}^{1} (x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6}) } dx} * (x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6})$ = $6\sqrt{5}(x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6})$

Comment: Hint:  Gram-Schmitt orthogonalization

Comment: Hey, I just tried Gram-Schmitt orthogonalization but I think it is wrong because when I use the inner product on the final vectors I got, they do not evaluate to 0.  I tried to compute v1 = 1 / (integral from 0 to 1 of 1) = 1/2, then v2 = 1 / (sqrt(integral of 0 to 1 of (x - 1/2)^2)) = 2sqrt(3)x. I stopped there because the first two did not compute to 0.

Comment: As a tip for future reference, MathJax does work in commenting too. I usually open an answer window to type then copy-paste from there. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Gram-Schimidt orthonormalization process can still be applied, provided you change the definitions of the inner product and the corresponding norm. For example, the inner product between $x$ and $x^2$ becomes:

$$\langle x,x^2 \rangle=\int_0^1 (x\cdot x^2)dx=\int_0^1x^3dx$$

And the norm of, say, $x$, becomes:
$$||x||=\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}=\sqrt{\int_0^1(x\cdot x) dx}=\sqrt{\int_0^1x^2dx}$$

---

**Edit:** Outlining the process:

Let $\{ u_1, u_2, u_3 \}$ be your non-normalized basis. You can begin with any power of $x$, but let's stick with $u_1=1$. Then we proceed to the second element using, say, the polynomial $x$:
$$u_2=x-\frac{\langle x,1\rangle}{\langle 1,1\rangle}1$$

Then we work for $u_3$:
$$u_3=x^2-\frac{\langle x^2,1\rangle}{\langle 1,1\rangle}1-\frac{\langle x^2,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}x$$

Then normalize the vectors. If they're not orthonormal, then you probably made a mistake onyour calculations or wriing the inner product (unless I wrote something wrong).

Comment: Hello thanks for help. I just tried Gram-Schmitt orthogonalization but I think it is wrong because when I use the inner product on the final vectors I got, they do not evaluate to 0.  I tried to compute v1 = 1 / (integral from 0 to 1 of 1) = 1/2, then v2 = 1 / (sqrt(integral of 0 to 1 of (x - 1/2)^2)) = 2sqrt(3)x. I stopped there because the first two did not compute to 0.

Comment: See edit. Trying to visualize the polynomials as (non-orthonormal) vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ might help in sketching the process.

Comment: I will update the original post with what I did.

Comment: Updated, did I do this correctly? thanks for all help btw.

Comment: I can't really work out calculation on actual paper right now, but WolframAlpha stated that the last polynomial should be $x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Thank you, now I see that the dot product evaluates to 0 between each, which means they are all orthogonal. is the answer these polynomials then? or do I need to do something with the norm next ?

Comment: You still need to normalize those vectors.

Comment: ok . I will update within a few minutes

Comment: Okay, I just re-read your question, and it asks for an *orthogonal* basis instead of *orthonormal*, so you didn't really need to divide by the norm. But it helps as an additional exercise. As a side note, I'd like to add that understanding this may help in Functional Analysis, if this area ever interests you again.

Comment: I think I finished correctly, could you please double-check ?

Comment: Oh ok. So just to clarify: the first set of vectors in my original post form an orthogonal basis, and the second set form an orthonormal basis? Thanks so much once again!

Comment: I think WolframAlpha is a better checker than me. Just type something like "integral_0^1 * insert polynomial here *". And about the orthogonal and orthonormal thing, you're correct. You can verify the vectors are orthogonal taking the inner products, and that they're normalized by calculating their norm.